# Is there any performance difference between these two JDBC Connectivity?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have used **MySqlDataSource** for in jdbc connectivity.I have used following code

```
MysqlDataSource d = new MysqlDataSource();
d.setUser("user");
d.setPassword("pass");
d.setServerName("hostname.com");
d.setDatabaseName("db");
Connection c = d.getConnection();
```

Also i have searched there is an option of [Configuring a MySQL Datasource in Apache Tomcat](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONF43/Configuring+a+MySQL+Datasource+in+Apache+Tomcat).

Is there any performance difference between these two? which one is best to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuring **Datasource** in tomcat will help you to share same data source between applications running in same **tomcat**. that **Datasource** will be managed by container (tomcat in your case).

while  the **Datasource** created in code will be created by your application and can be used by that application only.

So if you have multiple application running on tomcat and accessing same data source, that configuring **Datasource** in **tomcat** will be good approach  and have performance factor because only one data source is created and not having separate connections for each application

But if you have only single application that the first approach you have used is good one

Comment: `But if you have only single application that the first approach you have used is good one` You forgot about connection pooling.

Comment: yes @SJuan76 u are right, but I have given bit generalized statement here, as we also can implement connection pooling using code. Anyways thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

They both use the internally the same driver, i dont think the performance is much different here, i guess if you need to access teh database only at that place and the enduser isn't supposed to use his own authentication you may use it directly from java, but if you will need the connectivity on different places it could be helpful to configure this using apache configuration, specially that if anything changes like database server, user name or whatever you don't need to get in the code to change it, this could be very important if end users have to set their own configurations.

Answer (score 0):

The improvement of configuring a pool of `Connection`s (as the one provided by tomcat) is mainly that you will actually create and close a lot less of connections.

When using a pool, when you request a `Connection` to a pool it will look if it has any connection already created and available for reuse and, if it has, it will provide you with it (instead of creating a new  `Connection`, which is a heavy operation). You must still `close()` a  `Connection` provided by Tomcat so Tomcat knows that it can now reuse when it is requested again.

Additionally, the advantage of the pool is that your code does not need to know the configuration data for the `Connection`. He just requests a `Connection` from a given pool and the sysadmin configures it, allowing for greater flexibility (the sysadmin does not need to know how to configure your app, just how to configure the Tomcat which is fairly more standard).